# How to suppress #> output created by patchwork's plot_layout()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running code to use the `plot_layout` function from the `patchwork` library and find that for some plots, `plot_layout` creates the combined plot view, but also displays some messages prefixed by `#>`. How do I remove these messages from an R markdown file? Is there a chunk option I can use?

Here is my reprex:

````
``` r{corr-plots}
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(patchwork)
set.seed(123)

cor_100 <- as.data.frame(mvrnorm(100, mu = c(0,0), 
                 Sigma = matrix(c(1 ,1, 1, 1), ncol = 2), 
                 empirical = TRUE))

cor_70 <- as.data.frame(mvrnorm(100, mu = c(0,0), 
                 Sigma = matrix(c(1,0.7,0.7,1), ncol = 2), 
                 empirical = TRUE))

cor_100_plot <- ggplot(cor_100, aes(V1, V2)) + geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "Correlation = 1", y = "y", x = "x") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(cor_100$V2), lty = 2) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(cor_100$V1), lty = 2) + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 15) 

cor_70_plot <- ggplot(cor_70, aes(V1, V2)) + geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "Correlation = 0.7", y = "y", x = "x") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(cor_70$V2), lty = 2) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(cor_70$V1), lty = 2) + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 15)

plot_layout(cor_100_plot + cor_70_plot)
````

```

[image]

```
#> 
#> $nrow
#> NULL
#> 
#> $byrow
#> NULL
#> 
#> $widths
#> NULL
#> 
#> $heights
#> NULL
#> 
#> $guides
#> NULL
#> 
#> $tag_level
#> NULL
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "plot_layout"
```

Created on 2018-08-24 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Lin Pedersen answered me on Twitter. I had the syntax for plot_layout() all wrong. It should be `cor_100_plot + cor_70_plot + plot_layout()`.